# Terminating a thread : Python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

In the below example, if you execute the program multiple times, it spawns a new thread each time with a new ID. 
1. How do I terminate all the threads on task completion ? 
2. How can I assign name/ID to the threads ?

```
import threading, Queue 

THREAD_LIMIT = 3                 
jobs = Queue.Queue(5)           # This sets up the queue object to use 5 slots 
singlelock = threading.Lock()   # This is a lock so threads don't print trough each other 

# list  
inputlist_Values = [ (5,5),(10,4),(78,5),(87,2),(65,4),(10,10),(65,2),(88,95),(44,55),(33,3) ] 

def DoWork(inputlist): 
    print "Inputlist received..."
    print inputlist 

    # Spawn the threads 
    print "Spawning the {0} threads.".format(THREAD_LIMIT) 
    for x in xrange(THREAD_LIMIT): 
        print "Thread {0} started.".format(x) 
        # This is the thread class that we instantiate. 
        worker().start() 

    # Put stuff in queue 
    print "Putting stuff in queue"
    for i in inputlist: 
        # Block if queue is full, and wait 5 seconds. After 5s raise Queue Full error. 
        try: 
            jobs.put(i, block=True, timeout=5) 
        except: 
            singlelock.acquire() 
            print "The queue is full !"
            singlelock.release() 

    # Wait for the threads to finish 
    singlelock.acquire()        # Acquire the lock so we can print 
    print "Waiting for threads to finish."
    singlelock.release()        # Release the lock 
    jobs.join()                 # This command waits for all threads to finish. 

class worker(threading.Thread): 
    def run(self): 
        # run forever 
        while 1: 
            # Try and get a job out of the queue 
            try: 
                job = jobs.get(True,1) 
                singlelock.acquire()        # Acquire the lock 
                print self
                print "Multiplication of {0} with {1} gives {2}".format(job[0],job[1],(job[0]*job[1]))         
                singlelock.release()        # Release the lock 
                # Let the queue know the job is finished. 
                jobs.task_done() 
            except: 
                break           # No more jobs in the queue 


def main():    
    DoWork(inputlist_Values)
```

Comment: If you're worried about accidentally leaving threads lying around after exit, that's not possible. Besides, you explicitly `join`, so you can't exit until the threads are done anyway. So… what exactly is the problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: For your second question: threads already have some kind of ID, assigned by the OS, and you can assign a name by passing `name=` to the constructor, as [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) make clear.

Comment: Well, I can verify that your code looks like it should work.  IIRC, the thread should automatically terminate when hitting the end of it's flow of control.

Indulge me for a second: Are you using Eclipse, and having a problem with threads running after you think your program should be terminated?

Comment: Just an FYI, all the functionality you're implementing here is already available in the `multiprocessing` module (specifically, `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool`).

Comment: To answer the second question: IDs are not guaranteed to be reused (they may continue to increment even if threads die), and you can't set them yourself (since they are OS-specific thread identifiers). But, you can set thread names by assigning to the `name` property of a `Thread` object.

Comment: Program runs absolutely fine. Its just that if you execute the program again and observe console, new threadIDs are asssigned. Are the old threads termminated ? I am doing Join explicitly, but than run menthod execution is endless. I am confused if the threads are cleaned properly with my current approach.

Comment: @buffer_overflow: If the program exits, the old threads have finished and been cleaned up. There's no way that could not be true. If you run the program again, you get new threads. The thread IDs may or may not be the same—it depends on the OS whether this is very likely or very unlikely, but it doesn't really matter either way. You cannot be "leaking" threads here between runs of the program. Is that all you're asking, or is there some other problem here?

Comment: @nneonneo: I've added [code example based on `multiprocessing`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14271294/4279).

Comment: Wanted to confirm if there are "leaking" threads in my code or not. Thank you all for the inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I terminate all the threads on task completion?

You could put `THREAD_LIMIT` sentinel values (e.g., `None`) at the end of the queue and exit thread's `run()` method if a thread sees it.

On your main thread exit all non-daemon threads are joined so the program will keep running if any of the threads is alive. Daemon threads are terminated on your program exit.

> How can I assign name/ID to the threads ?

You can assign name by passing it to the constructor or by changing `.name` directly.

Thread identifier `.ident` is a read-only property that is unique among alive threads. It maybe reused if one thread exits and another starts.

---

You could rewrite you code using `multiprocessing.dummy.Pool` that provides the same interface as [`multiprocessing.Pool`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) but uses threads instead of processes:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import logging
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool

debug = logging.getLogger(__name__).debug

def work(x_y):
    try:
        x, y = x_y # do some work here
        debug('got %r', x_y)
        return x / y, None
    except Exception as e:
        logging.getLogger(__name__).exception('work%r failed', x_y) 
        return None, e

def main():
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
        format="%(levelname)s:%(threadName)s:%(asctime)s %(message)s")

    inputlist = [ (5,5),(10,4),(78,5),(87,2),(65,4),(10,10), (1,0), (0,1) ]
    pool = Pool(3)
    s = 0.
    for result, error in pool.imap_unordered(work, inputlist):
        if error is None:
           s += result
    print("sum=%s" % (s,))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

#### [Output](http://ideone.com/O50t0A)

```
DEBUG:Thread-1:2013-01-14 15:37:37,253 got (5, 5)
DEBUG:Thread-1:2013-01-14 15:37:37,253 got (87, 2)
DEBUG:Thread-1:2013-01-14 15:37:37,253 got (65, 4)
DEBUG:Thread-1:2013-01-14 15:37:37,254 got (10, 10)
DEBUG:Thread-1:2013-01-14 15:37:37,254 got (1, 0)
ERROR:Thread-1:2013-01-14 15:37:37,254 work(1, 0) failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prog.py", line 11, in work
    return x / y, None
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
DEBUG:Thread-1:2013-01-14 15:37:37,254 got (0, 1)
DEBUG:Thread-3:2013-01-14 15:37:37,253 got (10, 4)
DEBUG:Thread-2:2013-01-14 15:37:37,253 got (78, 5)
sum=78.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Threads don't stop unless you *tell them to stop*.

My recommendation is that you add a `stop` variable into your `Thread` subclass, and check whether this variable is `True` or not in your run loop (instead of `while 1:`).

An example:

```
class worker(threading.Thread): 
    def __init__(self):
         self._stop = False

    def stop(self):
         self._stop = True

    def run(self): 
        # run until stopped 
        while not self._stop:                 
            # do work
```

Then when your program is quitting (for whatever reason) you have to make sure to call the `stop` method on all your working threads.

About your second question, doesn't adding a `name` variable to your `Thread` subclass work for you?

Comment: Threads also stop if the thread function exits or if the process quits. In his case, the `break` should take care of the workers.

Comment: Of course, I meant that when the main process exits, threads won't stop unless you specifically tell them to.

Comment: Threads can be daemonized, in which case they will automatically exit when all non-daemon threads exit.

Comment: Well, that's another way to do the same thing I propose, you could make it an answer for the question too. I'm not so sure about this, but I believe that you can't control in wich point of the running code will the thread die, which can be a concern in some circunstances.